# When Junit Test with Spring throws Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, log4j, junit5

My service is running fine, but when I write a test it gives the error I specified.
I tried several methods but couldn't find the problem.

**dependency**

```
<spring-boot.version>2.7.4</spring-boot.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**My Bussiness class**

```
public class UserBusinessService {

    static Logger logger = LogFactory.getLogger(UserBusinessService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserBusinessService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteUserByUserId(id);
        logger.info("deleted");
    }
}
```

**MY Test Class**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserBusinessServiceTest {
    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    UserBusinessService userBusinessService;


    @Test
    void deleteUser_itShouldReturnStatusNotFound_whenUserNotExist() throws Exception {

        // given
        when(userRepository.deleteUserByUserId(anyLong()));

        // when
        Executable executable = () -> userBusinessService.deleteUser(1L);

        // then
        assertThrows(BusinessException.class, executable);
    }
}
```

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: The message is explicit: you have both `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-slf4j-impl` on your classpath. These are bridges from Log4j2 API to SLF4J and from SLF4J to Log4j2 API. These are probably _transitive_ dependencies brought by `spring-boot-starter-logging` (everything goes to Logback) and `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` (everything goes to Log4j2 Core). You need to exclude one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by exclusion like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```